# How to lower CPU usage extracting camera frames using AVFoundation on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, xcode8

I'm working on a machine learning project that needs to access camera frames at 60fps. Good picture quality is not a requirement, but processing time is.

On my trial to achieve light processor usage for frame extraction I'm changing `captureSession.sessionPreset` from `AVCaptureSessionPresetLow` to `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh` but the CPU usage keeps the same on an iPhone 6:

￼[image: AVCaptureSessionPresetLow]
[image: AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh]

Note: On both scenarios I'm forcing 60 fps:

`captureDevice.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 60)`
`captureDevice.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 60)`

I'm fine with the 192x144 resolution for the low preset but any clue on how to achieve better results regarding processor usage (5-10%)?

Comment: I am also facing similar issues. Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: I didn't, I'm sorry :/